# ¿Cómo obtener el total de objetos recuperados en una consulta?

Tags: adonisjs, adonis-5

a base de una consulta necesito saber el largo del objeto que se devuelve. Para ser un poco más explícito, necesito saber cuantos (en mi caso) "usuarios" se devuelven al realizar la consulta. La consulta que hago es esta:

```
const usuario = await Usuario.query().where('codigo', codigo)
.where('password', password).first() as unknown as Usuario
```

Hay 3 posibilidades, que no encuentre nada, que encuentre uno, o que encuentre más de uno, por lo que necesito saber el largo del arreglo (o al menos creo que lo que devuelve es un arreglo) para poder tomar decisiones después. La idea es que cuando yo reciba los datos de ingreso, buscarlos primero en la base de datos y después tomar decisiones con él, ya que al tener la posibilidad de tener más de un usuario igual debo hacer tal o cual cosa. Básicamente, necesito saber cuantos usuarios hay que coincidan con la búsqueda para luego tomar decisiones. Estoy utilizando `AdonisJs 5` con `TypeScript`. Muchas gracias y cualquier ayuda es bienvenida!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considera que:

- El método [`first`](https://docs.adonisjs.com/reference/database/query-builder#first) tiene 2 posibles valores de retorno

  - null, en caso de no encontrar resultados asociados

    ```
    null
    ```
  - El objeto con la data que empató con las condiciones establecidas

    ```
    {
        ...............
        ...............
        ...............
    }
    ```

En cualquiera de los 2 casos, la salida obtenida no se ajusta a lo que se lee en el enunciado (*pues expones que existe la posibilidad de poder traer mas de un registro*).

- Por ende tu consulta simplemente debería ser así:

  ```
  const usuario = await Usuario.query()
                               .where('codigo', codigo)
                               .where('password', password)
  ```

  - Que arrojará como salida un array de objetos similar a esto en caso de 2 o mas coincidencias:

    ```
      [
          {
              ...............
              ...............
          },
          {
              ...............
              ...............
          },
          {
              ...............
              ...............
          }
      ]
    ```
  - Así en caso de que solo exista un registro

    ```
      [
          {
              ...............
              ...............
          },
      ]
    ```
  - Y finalmente así en caso de no encontrar coincidencia alguna en los registros de tu base de datos

    ```
      []
    ```

**Opciones para obtener el conteo de objetos recuperados**

1. Por medio de la siguiente query se retornará la longitud del array (*verifica por favor el uso de paréntesis.*)

   ```
   const usuario = (await Usuario.query()
                                 .where('codigo', codigo)
                                 .where('password', password)).length
   ```

Notas:

- Al tratarse de un *array de objetos* puedes emplear la [propiedad `length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) para saber la cantidad de elementos que dicha estructura contiene.

  - En el caso específico del primer ejemplo serían: **3**, para el segundo seria **1** y para el último 0

2. O [contando directamente las filas recuperadas](https://docs.adonisjs.com/reference/database/query-builder#count) en la query así:

   ```
   const $usuarios = await Usuario.query().where('codigo', codigo)
                                     .where('password', password)
                                     .count({ total: '*' })
   ```

Que básicamente es un conteo de todas las filas de tu tabla vinculada al modelo `Usuario` que coincidan con las reglas establecidas.

En SQL sería algo como:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM tuTabla WHERE condicionUno AND condicionDos
```

Y obtendrías los datos accediendo de esta forma:

```
$usuarios[0].$extras.total
```

Es importante hacer notar que esta última query a diferencia de la primera no te va a devolver los valores de cada objeto que coincidera con los criterios dados (**es decir el email o el password**) si no únicamente el conteo de objetos que encontró (*es decir un valor numérico asociado a la clave total en el objeto `$extras`*)

Comentarios finales:

- Es un poco extraño que vayas a recuperar mas de 1 usuario con las mismas credenciales (*tal vez tengas que verificar este apartado*)
- Recomiendo revises la documentación del framework, es muy intuitiva y funcional para ir conociendo mas todas sus bondades

Comment: @LucaViotti listo edité la respuesta espero te ayude